# Placing a multipage pdf in InDesign CC2014

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign CC (new user) and have placed several pages of a multipage pdf by using the cursor on each sequential page.  Is there a way to automate this?  There are 63 pages in total.

Many thanks

Comment: @Scott: no. The title suggests it is but the topic of the other post is its size, not the number of pages. Strangely enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately there is no implemented option in indesign to do this.
the only way to solve the problem is [this script](http://indesignsecrets.com/zanelli-releases-multipageimporter-for-importing-both-pdf-and-indd-files.php).

hope it helps!